# How do I install Web API 1 from Nuget?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I want to use Web API 1 in a project (can't be 2) and I also want it to be installed from nuget.org.

So I went to it expecting to find a version *1 dot something*.
To my surprise I found a [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi) that happens to be on version 5.2.3.

**2.2** on **5.2.3**... okay, now I'm confused.

Anyway, it's possible to use Web API 1 from nuget.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Web API was introduced with ASP.NET MVC 4 RC. Web API 2.0 was introduced with MVC 5. Because these APIs are very similar and are heavily inspired by MVC that's why the version numbers are the way they are.

Anyways enough with the history lesson: you're looking for [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/4.0.20505). It's on the same page. Or alternatively:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 4.0.20505
```

From your Nuget console.

Answer (score 1):

Latest Version of Web API 1 is under [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 4.0.30506](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi/4.0.30506).

[image]